# Prevent scrolling in Android browser

Tags: android, webkit, scroll

Is there a way to prevent scrolling of a rendered HTML page in the Android browser? The following does not appear to have any impact on page scrolling in the Android browser:

```
var preventDefault = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
document.addEventListener('touchmove',preventDefault,false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',preventDefault,true);
window.addEventListener('touchmove',preventDefault,true);
```

(I've tried with bubbling on and off.)

It looks to me like Android Webkit makes the "window" the same length as the document, so scrolling is being done on the browser itself, not on the document body or DOM window object. What's weird is that that's exactly what webkit on iOS does, but the code above still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The problem ended up being that you need to capture and suppress `ontouchstart` as well as `ontouchmove` on `document` to stop the browser from scrolling. This is definitely different in iOS, but it still works identically on both platforms.

The actual code I ended up using looks sort of like this:

```
var preventDefault = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
};
var touchstart = function(e) {
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', preventDefault,false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove',  preventDefault,false);
    /*do other stuff*/
};
var touchend = function(e) {
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', preventDefault,false);
    document.removeEventListener('touchmove',  preventDefault,false);
};

element.addEventListener('touchstart',  touchstart, false);
element.addEventListener('touchend',    touchend,   false);
```

Comment: What is 'element' in this case?

Comment: @MrThys, I'm sorry. I honestly can't remember what it was, but I think it was probably the document body, though it could have been a `div`. I also can't remember if this was related to this problem, but I also found that you have to apply a "click" handler to prevent events from colliding. I ended up writing out certain `div`s with `onclick="void(0)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Not works on Chrome on Android though

But preventing event on window and stopping immediate propagation helps!

Handler should be not passive to do that.

MAY BE adding an event handler on `capturing` phase would help too

But this snippet below is tested by me

```
window.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, { passive: false });
```

DEMO https://codepen.io/ColCh/full/qvLqoe